# Beamer sidebar font problem

Tags: beamer, fonts, hungarian

I write a presentation in Hungarian. It often occurs that section title contains special Hungarian letters \H{o} or \H{u}. It is OK within the frame, but in the sidebar they appears as simple letters u and o. In my experience it is independent from the used styles. Is there some solution?

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\def\magyarOptions{hyphenation=huhyphn}

\begin{document}
\section{\scshape Tartalomjegyzék}
\begin{frame}
\transblindshorizontal
\title{Some Title}

\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép}
\begin{frame}{Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is probably a solution but it is hard to say anything more helpful without more information. Please post a Minimum Working Example which people can compile to reproduce your problem. This makes it a lot easier for people to help you - they can just cut-and-paste a small amount of code and compile it to see the problem and work on it.

Comment: Providing a Minimal Working Example (MWE) would be most helpful to those seeking to help you.  In the absence of that, `\protect` prior to a fragile macro often will resolve problems in special environments.

Comment: I think `\def\magyarOptions` after `\usepackage[magyar]{babel}` is both useless and unneeded. The magyar module needs the value of magyarOptions _during_ loading; and the hyphenation settings are AFAIK optimal with the default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\documentclass{beamer}
[ ... ]
```